# Python3 paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Приветствую все, помогите решить проблему: 
есть код

```
if switch in zhone:
        zhone_ip = zhone[switch]
        print (zhone_ip)
        paramiko.common.logging.basicConfig(level=paramiko.common.DEBUG)
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.RejectPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=zhone_ip, port=22, username='admin', password='zhone')
        channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
        channel.get_pty()
        channel.settimeout(5)
        channel.exec_command('onu status 1/7/52')
        print (channel.recv(1024))

        channel.close()
        ssh.close()

    `
```

вот выход :

```
    172.20.0.7
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x3dbd41d0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.0.1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-Mocana SSH
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client Mocana)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos:['diffie-hellman-group14-sha1', 'diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'] server key:['ssh-dss'] client encrypt:['aes256-cbc', 'rijndael256-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'rijndael192-cbc', 'aes128-cbc', 'rijndael128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'arcfour'] server encrypt:['aes256-cbc', 'rijndael256-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'rijndael192-cbc', 'aes128-cbc', 'rijndael128-cbc', '3des-cbc', 'arcfour'] client mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-md5-96'] server mac:['hmac-sha1', 'hmac-sha1-96', 'hmac-md5', 'hmac-md5-96'] client compress:['none'] server compress:['none'] client lang:[''] server lang:[''] kex follows?False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex agreed: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Cipher agreed: aes128-cbc
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:MAC agreed: hmac-md5
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Compression agreed: none
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Unknown exception: p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Traceback (most recent call last):
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1772, in run
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_group1.py", line 75, in parse_next
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return self._parse_kexdh_reply(m)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_group1.py", line 111, in _parse_kexdh_reply
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    self.transport._verify_key(host_key, sig)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1620, in _verify_key
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    if not key.verify_ssh_sig(self.H, Message(sig)):
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 153, in verify_ssh_sig
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    ).public_key(backend=default_backend())
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py", line 194, in public_key
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return backend.load_dsa_public_numbers(self)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py", line 198, in load_dsa_public_numbers
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    return b.load_dsa_public_numbers(numbers)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 702, in load_dsa_public_numbers
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    dsa._check_dsa_parameters(numbers.parameter_numbers)
ERROR:paramiko.transport:  File "/home/kocik/python/xls/xls/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py", line 120, in _check_dsa_parameters
ERROR:paramiko.transport:    raise ValueError("p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long")
ERROR:paramiko.transport:ValueError: p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long
```

в чем проблема не пойму, может вы подскажете?

Comment: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/750

Comment: Старайтесь приводить минимальные но полные примеры кода и соответсвующее *словесное* описание что код должен делать и что вместо этого происходит (чем конкретно вывод отличается от желаемого  и какая из нескольких возможных проблем вас интересует). Более информативный заголовок не повредит: "Попытка ssh на zphone используя paramiko 2 приводит к ValueError: p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long"